# MongoDB ETL into HDFS

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hdfs, etl

I want to be able to move my MongoDB production data to HDFS through a continuous ETL pipeline so as to be able to run Spark/MR jobs on it.

I know that Hadoop MongoDB Connector exists to read/write data from/to MongoDB, but I don't want to incur network I/O and hence, I would ideally want to set up an ETL pipeline to read diff from MongoDB and write into HDFS.

For obvious reasons, I would not like to copy the entire collection to HDFS periodically and only copy the diff.

Any suggestions how can I achieve this ?

What I am thinking of right now is to read MongoDB op-logs and apply these op-logs on previous DB snapshot (already saved in HDFS) to create current MongoDB snapshot in HDFS.

Is there anything better that I can do ?

Comment: Did you work on this approach?

Comment: We solved the problem a bit differently. We read bin logs from Mongo, uploaded them to S3 and then wrote the said job in Spark to maintain latest snapshot in HDFS/S3

Comment: I have a similar usecase to be solved. Can we discuss more on chat or email or phone? Here is my profile link: Please connect if it is okay for you!!! https://www.linkedin.com/in/anuj-aneja-06713b20?trk=hp-identity-name

Comment: anuj.ymca@gmail.com

Comment: can anyone send details of the approach.